Why in Cordova, EventSource and/or fetch do not behave the same way they behave in a browser like chrome, when fetching SseEmitter tokens?
In Google chrome for example, EventSource and/or fetch are getting the packages from a SseEmitter endpoint, one by one, so that I can get the ChatGPT tokens generation effect.
But in my Cordova app, in both Android and iOS, the tokens generation effect is not possible, as EventSource and fetch calls, are buffering the backend response, delivering the text to the javascript code in a single push, after the server stopped emitting.
Any idea why this behavior in Cordova? Is it possible to get the same tokens generation effect in Cordova without using a websocket connection?
JS code for EventSource approach:
function handleGptSuggestCallEventSource(params, target) {
    let eventSource = mwSuggestEventSource(params)
    
     eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
         if (event.data.includes(FINAL_MESSAGE)) {
            eventSource.close();  // Stop the EventSource
            return;
        } else {
            let formattedText = event.data.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');
            formattedText = formattedText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
            formattedText = formattedText.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');

            updateTargetMessage(formattedText, target);
        }
    };

    eventSource.onerror = function(err) {
        eventSource.close();
    };
    
}

function mwSuggestEventSource(params) {
    return callGPTEventSource(GPT_SUGGEST_URL.format(params));
}


function  callGPTEventSource(url) {
    try {
        return new EventSource(getFullURL(url));
    } catch (e) {
        showToastError(getStr(e));
    }
}

Java code for BE:
 public SseEmitter callApiAsync(HttpRequest request) {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                
                client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream())
                .thenAccept(response -> {
                    try (InputStream inputStream = response.body()) {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        String line;
                        Matcher matcher;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            matcher = GPT_TEXT_PATTERN.matcher(line);
                            if (matcher.find()) {
                                line = matcher.group(1);
                            } else {
                                line = "";
                            }
                            line = line.replace(" ", EMPTRY_SPACE);
                            emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().data(line)); // Stream each line to client
                        }
                        emitter.send(FINAL_MESSAGE);
                        emitter.complete(); // Complete the emitter after finishing reading
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        emitter.completeWithError(e);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.completeWithError(e);
            }
        });

        return emitter;
    }


Not sure what you mean by "fetch calls are caching the backend response"

@Eric, you are right, "caching" is not the right term here. What i mean is "buffering" the backed response. It waits for  the complete message to be pushed by the server, before making it available to the JS code.

OK so what's the issue with that? I still don't understand the problem here. You can't receive half a JSON response ...

@Eric, EventSource doesn't send Json. It sends text tokens, one at a time. Because of the problem I've mentioned, I cannot get the effect you get when you interact with ChatGPT:  the tokens typing effect.  Due to the problem I'm facing, my apps users will have to 1: wait a considerable amount of time to get something on the screen, 2: the whole message sent by the Backend, is being presented to them in one shut. I'm reiterating it here, this behavior is only visible in Cordova apps. In a standard web browser, the same code works ok, being able to get that ChatGPT tokens printing effect.

Is it socket based? Please post some code, and your content security policy.

You probably have an issue with the socket, which fallbacks onto long polling which is basically interval fetching every x seconds, which might be why you aren't getting a realtime response.

Is not websocket. That is what I want to avoid. I've added to the post the relevant JS and Java code. Again the problem is strictly related to the Cordova applications. I suspect there is either a problem or a limitation with the WebView

EventSource is not websocket BUT it is still a socket with only 1 direction (server to client). What's your content security policy for EventSource ?

Also one thing that feels odd in your code is that you recreate the EventSource every time instead of re-using the existing connection. Why?

No particular reasons. I just ended up writing it like this for these tests.

Well, you need to fix this first and re-use the existing connection. That might be a good start. Because everytime you use the function callGPTEventSource, you destroy the previous stream.

Yeah, but the user can only call callGPTEventSource once, whiteout having to destroy the   previous prompt first, making this way the previous connection irrelevant. Is not this, that's 100% sure.

Just for the record, I did some tests trying to reuse the eventSource connection, but actually that won't work, as I am calling eventSource.close(); when I get the final message.  This action will close the eventSource connection, making it unusable. My original approach is actually ok as it creates a new connection each time I call the method. This action, is not interfering with the existing  EventSources.

Are you testing via the Android emulator or physical device?

physical devices and emulators  are behaving the same

When working with Cordova, EventSource and fetch APIs may not behave the same way they do in a standard desktop browser like Chrome due to several factors specific to the Cordova environment.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
